# What is a good way to format a CSV file to be crawled in AWS Glue?

Tags: csv, aws-glue

I currently have a CSV file with 200k lines that look like this

id,path,username,folderid

32423423424,asfasf-232-3,cooluser,234324-234-34324-424

When the crawler finishes, it does say it created the table and I can see the table details. When I try to preview the data in athena it returns zero records. The CSV file is stored in a S3 bucket, all permissions are correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the file inside a particular folder and point the crawler towards the folder. I think this would work rather than pointing towards a particular file.